# En que momento es que le pasamos los argumentos al metodo print de la clase printerJob

Tags: java

Se me olvido mencionar que lo que quiero es **ENTENDER** como funciona el paso de argumentos.

Este codigo lo uso para imprimir un ticket (en una impresora termica con un ancho de 80mm) y funciona correctamente **no tiene** errores.

Mi pregunta es: En que momento es que se le pasan los argumentos al metodo print de la clase printerJob.

```
        printerJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
        Paper paper = new Paper();

        paper.setImageableArea(10, 0, 200, 100);
        pf.setPaper(paper);

        pj.setPrintable(new Impresora(), pf);


          try {

            pj.print();
          } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
          }
```

En la linea:

```
pj.print();
```

se utiliza el metodo `print` pero no le pasamos ningun argumento.

En otra clase que implementa printable es donde se tiene el metodo `print` que es el que llamamos en la linea de código que les mostre arriba, y donde se ve que es necesario pasarle argumentos pero no lo hacemos, por que como se mustra solo ponemos " `pj.prit();` " sin argumentos.

La clase `Impresora` es donde tengo el metodo `print` y es como se muestra a continuación:

```
  class Impresora implements Printable 
  {
  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex != 0)
      return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    Date fecha = new Date();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);

    g2.drawString("Fecha "+fecha.getDate()+"-"+(fecha.getMonth()+1)+"-"+(fecha.getYear()+1900)+"   Hora "+fecha.getHours()+":"+fecha.getMinutes(), 10, 20);

    Rectangle2D outline = new Rectangle2D.Double(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY(), pf.getImageableWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight());
    g2.draw(outline);
    return PAGE_EXISTS;

}
}
```

En que momento se le pasan los argumentos al método:

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Estás comparando el método `print` de la clase `printerJob` con el de la clase `Impresora`. No veo la relación.

Comment: Aqui: `pj.setPrintable(new Impresora(), pf)`

Comment: En lugar de pasar parámetros en el método, lo que se hace es añadir los valores necesarios en propiedades de la clase mediante el setter `setPrintable`. El método `print` usa esas propiedades.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando llamas a

```
pj.print();
```

estás llamando al imprimir de la clase PrinterJob, es decir, nunca llamas a

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
```

ya que es un método de la clase Impresora y estás llamando al de PrinterJob